# NuGet.Server Bad Request

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I am currently trying to setup a NuGet server on our intranet but I'm having a problem.  I'm following the instructions here:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

The website works fine, but when I try to point the package manager at the source I get an error:

"Could not connect to the feed specified at 'myserver/DataServices/Packages.svc'.  Please verify the package source (located in the Package Manager Settings) is valid and ensure your network connectivity."

The URL is correct, copied from the website and is "http://myserver/nuget".

Using Fiddler I inspected the data transfer and I get:

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="en-AU">Bad Request - Error in query syntax.</message>
</error>
```

There are no error logs I can find on the server.

Can anyone help with this?  I'd really like to use NuGet.Server but I'm out of ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are  you running the lastest versions of both the NuGet.Server and the Package Manager in VS?

Comment: Yes we are, on both my local environment and on the server.  IIS 7 on the server also, visual studio locally

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed ASP.NET MVC 3 on the server?

Are you pointing the client directly at the base URL, or at the .svc endpoint? You should use the base URL - the call semantics have changed recently.